# using DataAnnotations to validate Model, not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have this code on an Entity created using EF 4:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MemberMetaData))]
public partial class Member
{
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [PropertiesMustMatch("Password", "ConfirmPassword", ErrorMessage = "Password and confirm password do not match.")]
    public class MemberMetaData
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required.")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Email is invalid.")]
        //[RegularExpression(@"^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$")]
        public object Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [DisplayName("Password")]
        public object Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [DisplayName("Confirm Password")]
        public object ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Members properties in the Member entity are Email and Password so far.

I'm trying to use the data annotations to return a validation message back to the view and have created a unit test like so:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void register_post_displays_error_when_email_not_entered()
    {
        // Arrange
        Member model = new Member()
        {
            Email = "",
            Password = "test123",
            ConfirmPassword = "test123"
        };
        // Act
        var result = _controller.Register(model) as ViewResult;
        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual("Email is required.", result.ViewData.ModelState["Email"].Errors[0].ErrorMessage);
    }
```

This is failing, when I step into the controller ModelState.IsValid is always true. Here's my controller action:

```
 [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Register(Member model)
         {
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             { //register
             }

             // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
             return View("Register");
         }
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Just an update the namespace on my partial class matches that of my entity.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [tutorial](http://johan.driessen.se/posts/testing-dataannotation-based-validation-in-asp.net-mvc)

The model binder is not being invoked so the validation is not taking place.

You can do it manually using the following

```
var validationContext = new ValidationContext(user, null, null);
var validationResults = new List<ValidationResult>();
Validator.TryValidateObject(user, validationContext, validationResults);
foreach (var validationResult in validationResults)
{
    controller.ModelState.AddModelError(validationResult.MemberNames.First(), validationResult.ErrorMessage);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Aros, I managed to get this working last night/early this morning by adding TryValidateModel(model) prior to checking ModelState.IsValid. How does that differ to the solution you provided, am I calling this unnecessarily?

Comment: That does the same thing and is much less code, it just performs the model binding which then invokes the validation. However it means you are binding the model twice now in your controller (framework auto and manually)? Whereas the code above doesn't add extra code to controller for testing?